# Multi inbound networks on one switch - is it possible to mitigate high latency?

Tags: vlan, dell, powerconnect

I am rather new to VLAN setups, and I am not sure if I understand the basic implementation. To save some bits, I'll attempt a quick and dirty run down of my setup.

Here is a crude picture(drawing) to start - 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5EkiD8tb1Z9SnhaOU12ZXRSOHM/view?usp=sharing

I have the internet feed coming into my basement to the ISPs "ONT". From there, it runs to a switch(Dell PowerConnect 2748), port 48 if it helps, and set to unmanaged mode. I then have a consumer grade router connected to port 47. It is able to pick up the dynamic IP from the ISP with no issues.

I then connect 4 nix-based servers to the ports on that router and create a 10.2.40.xxx subnet. They are all able to pickup the internet connection from the router just fine, and I configure the IP's in a static fashion. This router also servers up DHCP for all of my wireless devices up stairs(phones, xbox, laptops, etc) with no issues.

In my basement, I have 4 more nix-based servers. 2 of them have static public IP addresses provided by my ISP, and they connect to ports 45 and 46 on the switch. They are picking up the network connection and all is well.

What I have done next was ran a cable from the upstairs router(port1), down to the basement switch(port 1). This allows the basement servers access to the servers upstairs over the 10.2.40.xxx subnet.

This setup appears to be working, however, there is a very obvious jump in overall latency on both sides. The overall speed doesn't appear to affected as when the speedtest.net finally did load, I was able to get it to show a download of 234MB/s. There were still a lot of timeouts and high latency responses.

I am hoping that putting the switch in "managed" mode might allow me to separate the public and private networks. PErhaps the VLAN and/or LAG settings?

Is what I'm doing here even considered natural in the neteng world? I have set this up applying what ive learned as a sysadmin, and cannot say that my network terminology is correct >.<

Regards,
DDS

Comment: It weird setup. Worst - is DHCP working on ISP interface. Hard to say what is cause of latency. You get good speedtest.com result on upper floor? I ask to exclude "consumer grade router" performance problem. Also You can try make test between servers on "up stairs".

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on Server Fault for a business network, or on Super User for a personal network.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Dell switch to 'managed mode' and create an external vlan for all devices outside your NAT router (in your case 45-48 for the two servers, internet and NAT router's outside interface).

If you want to get further into the networking part, then move the rest of your ports off of vlan 1 to something else, but for home use you would be OK.

I would expect a DHCP device connected to the internal vlan would occasionally pick up an public IP and bypass the limited security your NAT router is providing for you. You can demonstrate this by shutting down your router and watching 'internal' devices pick up a public IP.

Comment: external vlan must also include ports 45 and 46 (separate network cards in servers with public IPs)

Comment: Whoops.  Nice catch.